# Linux folder move access

Tags: linux, filesystems, elevated-privileges

Is a Linux file system able to allow or deny the right to move a folder?  Active Directory does not, as far as I can tell. I'm curious, and 3 different wordings generated no results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have a folder `foo/bar/`, you could make the folder `foo` read-only, which would prevent people from moving `bar`:

```
$ chmod a-w foo
$ mv foo/bar ack
mv: cannot move ‘foo/bar’ to ‘ack’: Permission denied
```

The can't move `bar`, but they can still change what's inside of it:

```
$ echo hello > foo/bar/hello.txt
$ rm foo/bar/hello.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can use [chattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) to make a file or folder immutable like so:

```
chattr +i file
```

This way, not even the super can move, modify or delete the file.

To revert it you can use:

```
chattr -i file
```

This works for on ext filesystems